# Why doesn't this give the right output?

Tags: haskell

```
count :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
count _[]                  = 0
count z (x:xs) | z == x    = 1 + (count z xs)
               | otherwise = count z xs

rmdups :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
rmdups [] = []
rmdups (x:xs) | count x xs > 0 = rmdups xs
              | otherwise     = x: rmdups xs
```

The code above compiles but when I input `'ababca'` the output of rmdups is `'bca'` and I want it to be `'abc'`. Why does the a go there? I've been changing the code so much and have no clue why it does this.

Answer (score 10):

Because you remove the duplicates from the front. You could modify `rmdups` to filter out `xs` before moving on, so the duplicates are weeded out from the tail:

```
rmdups :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
rmdups [] = []
rmdups (x:xs)
    | count x xs > 0 = x : (rmdups $ filter (/= x) xs)
    | otherwise      = x : rmdups xs
```

In fact, you could even do this without precounting:

```
rmdups :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
rmdups []       = []
rmdups (x : xs) = x : filtered
                where filtered = rmdups $ filter (/= x) xs
```

And of course, in real code, you should rather prefer already-available functions, in this case [`Data.List.nub`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:nub).

Answer (score 1):

Your `rmdups` function removes all except the *last* occurrence of each character.

If you want to remove all except the *first* occurrence of each character, you could try

```
reverse . rmdups . reverse
```

(i.e., reverse before and after using rmdups), or you could rewrite `rmdups` to keep track of all characters that have previously occurred.